# php 7.3 can not open hidden session (session_id() fails to set id)

Tags: php, session, warnings

I have a php application that opens a session and sends the appropriate cookie to the browser like normal.

Somewhere in the script I want to close the current session, **silently** open a new one in the background, get some values from this "background session", close it again and resume the main session (the one the user got cookies for).

In Debian Stretch having **PHP 7.0** the following minimal example worked like a charm but now in **PHP 7.3** (Debian Buster) I get several warnings and the example ceases to work.

Expected output (as in PHP 7.0):

```
Main session closed now...<br>
Read data '10' and closed hidden session again...<br>
Main session resumed...<br>
```

Actual output (as in PHP 7.3):

```
Main session closed now...<br>
Warning: session_id(): Cannot change session id when headers already sent
Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent
Read data '' and closed hidden session again...<br>
Warning: session_id(): Cannot change session id when headers already sent
Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent
Main session resumed...<br>
```

Minimal (not-) working example:

```
$options=array('use_cookies'=>false, 'cache_limiter'=>'');
session_start();
$main_id=session_id();
$_SESSION["value"] = "xxx";
session_write_close();
echo "Main session closed now...<br>\n";
flush();

session_id("IdOfHiddenSession");
session_start($options);
$count=$_SESSION['count']++;
session_write_close();
echo "Read data '$count' and closed hidden session again...<br>\n";
flush();

session_id($main_id);
session_start($options);
echo "Main session resumed...<br>\n";
flush();
```

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Your use of  `echo` causes output (obviously) which is why you're getting the messages about headers already sent.

Comment: @Dave Yes I know, but that should not prevent me from opening a session if I disable sending cookies or using trans_sid for this session because no headers need to be send in this case --> no need to bail out because of headers already sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to disable session cookies **for all sessions** on script start instead of allowing cookies for the first `session_start()` and disabling them for subsequent `session_start()` calls.

**You have to send the cookie for the main session yourself in this case!**

So on script start do:

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);
```

And set the cookie yourself, if needed:

```
header("Set-Cookie: {$name}={$id}; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict");
```

The example code of the question thus becomes this:

```
//do this *only* on script start before headers are sent
if(!headers_sent())
{
    session_cache_limiter('');
    ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);
}

session_start();
$main_id=session_id();
//send cookie
header("Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID={$main_id}; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict");
$_SESSION["value"] = "xxx";
session_write_close();
echo "Main session closed now...<br>\n";
flush();

session_id("IdOfHiddenSession");
session_start();
$count=$_SESSION['count']++;
session_write_close();
echo "Read data '$count' and closed hidden session again...<br>\n";
flush();

session_id($main_id);
session_start();
echo "Main session resumed...<br>\n";
flush();
```